# using multiple dbcontexts and could not find original database

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have codefirst existing database model it was loading my database tables to choose from and generate code.
I moved my dbcontext file to a different class library which also worked fine. but it is probably creating aspnet user tables somewhere else although the connection string in web.config points to the same db.

My webconfig had two connections 1 was being created by default on SqlServer and another was mySQl connection. I tried to merge them and ended up here.

Note: I have a MySqlDb and i made some changes to adjust migrations key and now everything came down. **Now it doesnot find any of my original db tables**

[image]

**Now Details**
I have 3 projects

- GE.Entities (manually created all entities)
- GE.Core (GEContext)
- GE.Web (ApplicationDbContext & IdentityDbContext * IdentityModel )

I want these tables and my original db tables to be in the same database
I also want to move ApplicationDbContext to GE.Core. Is it posssible?

Also, i did migrations twice could it be the reason of breakdown?

MySql Migration classes (MySqlInitializer and MySqlHistoryContext) are passed GEContext when initialized

I know I am confusing a lot of things..please bear with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use IP address in the connection string instead of localhost and it worked!